# What Leibniz should I read if I want to better understand Voltaire?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, leibniz

I keep hearing that Voltaire's Candide is written in response to the ideas of Leibniz. If I wanted to get a better understanding of Voltaire, which works by Leibniz would be most pertinent for me to read?

Thanks

Comment: Leibniz's [*Theodicy*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-evil/).

Comment: Thank you. As far as Leibniz's texts go, are there any that are of particular importance as primers before reading Theodicy?